# how to select multiple items in ListBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I select multiple item in ListBox in VB.NET code.
Example:
I have item 1, 5, 8 -  then I want to select those items in ListBox in page load

```
ListBoxSample item
Item “aa1” Value =1
Item “aa2” Value =2
Item “aa3” Value =3
Item “aa4” Value =4
Item “aa5” Value =5
Item “aa6” Value =6
Item “aa7” Value =7
Item “aa8” Value =8
```

Comment: `Page_Load` means ASP.NET or is it a `Winforms` `ListView`(or even WPF)?

Comment: Only one item can be selected in an [ASP.NET-`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you selecting these based on values stored in a database, user input after postback, or something else?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders there seems to be quite a debate in that regard. ;P I would use them only if it made no sense otherwise (ie. if they were necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to ensure that multiple items can be selected(default is single-selection). Therefore use the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)-property:

```
<asp:ListBox id="listBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">aa1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">aa2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">aa3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">aa4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">aa5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">aa6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">aa7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">aa8</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

In an ASP.NET-[`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) there is no [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx) property or something like that. So you need to loop them and set the `ListItem`'s `Selected` property accordingly:

```
string[] selectedValues = { "1", "5", "8" };  // from session or whatever

foreach (ListItem item in listBox1.Items)
    item.Selected = selectedValues.Contains(item.Value);
```

Remember to do that only `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` and not on every postback in `Page_Load`. Otherwise you're overwriting the user-changes and  the `SelectedIndexChanged`-event won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

To enable multi selection you need to set the  `selection mode` to multiple in windows application

```
 ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
 ListBox1.SetSelected(1, True)
 ListBox1.SetSelected(5, True)
 ListBox1.SetSelected(8, True)
```

If it is **ASP `listBox`** then you can statically selected items as

```
<asp:ListBox id="drop1" rows="3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem selected="true">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem selected="true">Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem selected="true">Item 8</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

If you want to set it **dynamically** means you can use

```
  drop1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
  drop1.Items(0).Selected = True
  drop1.Items(1).Selected = True
  drop1.Items(2).Selected = True
```